# No puedo crear una foreign key en MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, mariadb, backend

Esto es lo que escribo:

`alter table  T_reserva add constraint pk_codHotel foreign key (codHotel) references T_hotel(codHotel);`

Esta es la tabla `T_hotel.codHotel`:

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| tipo           | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| numMaxPersonas | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| disponibilidad | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| codHotel       | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| precio         | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

En esta tabla esta que tiene la primary key `T_reserva.codHotel` que quiero referenciar hacia la tabla `T_hotel.codHotel`:

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| fechaLlegada  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| numNoches     | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| numAdultos    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| numMenDos     | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| numMenDosDoce | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| localizador   | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| observaciones | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| precio        | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| regimen       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| codCliente    | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| codHotel      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| tipoHab       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
  +---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Cuando quiero hacer la foreign key me tira:

`ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table`reservas`.`#sql-4e18_22`(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")`

Aca estan los scripts the  cada tabla:

T_reserva:

```
   `T_reserva | CREATE TABLE `T_reserva` (
  `fechaLlegada` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `numNoches` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `numAdultos` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `numMenDos` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `numMenDosDoce` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `localizador` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `observaciones` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `precio` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `regimen` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `codCliente` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `codHotel` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipoHab` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`localizador`),
  KEY `codCliente` (`codCliente`),
  CONSTRAINT `T_reserva_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`codCliente`) REFERENCES `T_cliente` (`codCliente`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

T_hotel:

```
  `T_hotel | CREATE TABLE `T_hotel` (
  `tipo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `numMaxPersonas` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `disponibilidad` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `codHotel` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `precio` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tipo`,`codHotel`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Tu columna `codHotel` es doblemente incoherente. Fíjate que en una tabla le dices que no admita NULL y luego le dices que su valor por defecto sea NULL (1ª incoherencia). Luego quieres relacionarla con la columna de la otra tabla que sí admite NULL. No puedes relacionar dos columnas por PK, si una admite NULL pero la otra no (2ª incoherencia). Si ya hay datos en las tablas debes normalizar ambas columnas y verificar que no hay valores nulos en ninguna de las dos con respecto a esa columna antes de crear la restricción.

Comment: Pero es sucede cuando agregas una primary ley. .se hace null automáticamente..con codClientre no tuve ningún problema y era el mismo caso...

Comment: El hecho de que haya funcionado en alguna columna, no significa que tengas que descuidar la coherencia en tu definición de datos. Incluso eso que ahora funciona te dará problemas a la larga si defines dos columnas relacionados con atributos o tipos de datos dispares.

Comment: Hice lo que me dijiste y no funciona: `alter table T_reserva modify column codHotel varchar(255) not null; y me sigue tirando el mismo error..
`

Comment: La estructura de la base de datos lo saque de un trabajo final de la universidad de Barcelona..

Comment: No es necesario que agregues la palabra **Solucionado**, no estamos en otras web donde necesitas hacerlo una vez encontraste la solución al problema, el recuadro verde con relleno muestra que la pregunta ya fue respondida y aceptada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resuelto: La columna a referenciar era parte de una foreign key compuesta por eso no tenia el `index` con `ALTER TABLE T_hotel add  index(codHotel) ;` lo solucione.

[Aca encontre la solucion](http://www.inspire-software.com/en/index/view/mysql-ERROR-1005-Cant-create-table-errno-150.html)

En la pagina dice:

`One of the fields in the relationship is part of a combination 
(composite) key and does not have it’s own individual index. Even though the field has an index as part of the composite key, you must create a separate index for only that key field in order to use it in a constraint. (Thanks to Alex for this tip)`

El comando `SHOW CREATE DATABASE reservas;` especifica el error.